# .NET dump analysis using windbg

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windbg, crash-dumps

I am debugging a .NET 3.5 CLR dump using windbg and [psscor2.dll](http://blog.coryfoy.com/2010/04/first-look-at-psscor2-the-new-windbg-debugging-extension-for-managed-code/) extension.
Code where exception happened looks like this:

```
try 
{
 ...
}
catch
{
 ...
}
catch
{
 ...
}
finally
{
 ...
 // exception I found in the dump happened here.
 ...
}
```

Ok, so with `!pe` command I have an exception. It is a null reference exception, but the real cause of the problem is somewhere above, in the try, or in one of the catches, and exception that happened there is masked by this one in the finally block. App crashed in the stress testing, so it is not easy to create a repro, so dump is everything I have.

So, question for the all windbg/.NET internals gurus out there. Do you have any idea how I can get exceptions that happened before this one in the finally block. I don't see anything useful on the stack (`!dso` command) and that is more or less where my psscor2 knowledge ends :).

Thanks.

Comment: No, that info fell into the bit-bucket.  Running the stress test with a debugger attached is a very simple workaround.  Make it stop on first-chance exceptions.

Comment: Running the stress test is not an option here, unfortunately. This is kind of complicated infrastructure, and tests are run in the lab. I don’t have anything but the repro. I hoped that exception thrown above is still somewhere on the stack/heap wherever. I guess it is still somewhere in the dump, but I just don’t have any idea where to find it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you haven't allready done, try !dae (DumpAllExceptions) and “!Analysis” command for dump-files. Finally the !analyze -v . Maybe you see something in the output.

Comment: I tried !dae. !analyze doesn't work so well with managed dumps.  Finally I opened a dump in a hex editor and searched for the "exception" keyword and some methods around the exception. It only found those nullreferenceexceptions so Hans Passant was right. Thanks.

Comment: If you're lucky you may be able to find the instance on the heap. However, you basically have to search the heap for instance of any exception (and keep in mind that you will find false positives). I don't know how to link the hidden exception to the one in the finally block, but you may be able to pinpoint it from the stack trace.

Comment: If you can run the stress test again some day you could try run a session with [intellitrace](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/04/28/useintellitracewithoutvsnet/) logging your code. This would give you more information about past events.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use windbg attatch to your process, execute "sxe clr" and wait for any null reference 1st chance exceptions and use !pe command to check callstack.
2. You can use "!dumpheap -type Exception" to find the objects which name include word "Exception", and then find the NullReferenceException objects, use .foreach(ex {!dumpheap -short -mt }){!pe ex}
3. You can find the parameters or local variables from !dso or !clrstack -a